# Изменение значений в ячейках JTable при изменении редактора ячеек

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Подскажите переопределил редактор ячеек для того, что бы избежать неправильного ввода, при этом значения в ячейках не сохраняются, подскажите как исправить ситуацию.

```
private JTable levayaJTable ()
    {
        String[]dannie=new String[]{
                "Фамилия","Имя","Отчество","Личный номер","Число, месяц, год рождения",
                "Место рождения (согласно паспорта)","Серия и номер паспорта","Дата выдачи","Кем выдан",
                "Код подразделения","Серия и номер удост. личности (Военного билета)","Дата выдачи(ВБ)",
                "Кем выдано","ИНН"
        };
        JTable levayaJTable=new JTable(new OsnovTable(dannie));
        levayaJTable.setRowHeight(20);
        levayaJTable.setOpaque(false);
        levayaJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
                .setCellEditor(new MaskEditor(new JFormattedTextField()));

        return levayaJTable;
    }
    //Модель основной таблицы
    private class OsnovTable extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        String[]dannie;
        HashMap<String,String>data=new HashMap<>();
        public OsnovTable(String[]dannie) {
            this.dannie=dannie;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dannie.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex==0)return dannie[rowIndex];
            if (columnIndex==1) return data.get(dannie[rowIndex]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex==0)return false;
            if (columnIndex==1)return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.put(dannie[rowIndex], (String) aValue);
        }
    }

    //Создание редактора таблицы
    private class MaskEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
    {
        public MaskEditor(JTextField textField) {
            super(textField);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            JFormattedTextField result= (JFormattedTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
            MaskFormatter dateMask;
                try
                {
                    if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).equals("Число, месяц, год рождения")
                            ||table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).equals("Дата выдачи"))
                    {
                        dateMask=new MaskFormatter("##.##.####");
                    result=new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
                    }
                    if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).equals("Серия и номер паспорта"))
                    {
                        dateMask=new MaskFormatter("#### ######");
                        result=new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
                    }
                    result.setBorder(new LineBorder(null,0));
                    return result;
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема кроется в создании своего *JFormattedTextField* в методе  *getTableCellEditorComponent* без навешивания на него дополнительных слушателей, которые вызовут fireEditingStopped()/fireEditingCanceled().

Я бы посмотрел на реализацию *javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor*, где используется    *javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate*, в конструкторе там есть такой фрагмент:

```
   ... 
   delegate = new EditorDelegate() {
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            textField.setText((value != null) ? value.toString() : "");
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return textField.getText();
        }
    };
    textField.addActionListener(delegate);
```

Хотя в целом, кажется разумнее в метод setCellEditor(new MaskEditor(new JFormattedTextField())) передавать созданный и уже настроенный JFormattedTextField, с нужной маской. Тогда и отдельный класс MaskEditor не нужен, достаточно DefaultCellEditor.

Comment: Спасибо, но как настроить setCellEditor? В модели? Ведь у меня для каждой строки свой JFormattedTextField.

Comment: Обычно используется один (экземпляр) редактор ячейки для всех строк колонки, когда ячейка становится редактируемой, она устанавливает свое значение для редактора и переиспользуется. Если же  для разных строк нужны разные редакторы, то все становится сложнее.

Comment: Так в том и дело, что задача стоит в том, чтобы избежать неправильный ввод. Есть способ как увязать модель таблицы с JFormattedTextField?